Looking to create column names from top rows in dataframe
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19
0   9.0     8.0     7.0     6.0     5.0     4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     5.0     6.0     7.0     8.0 9   .0
1   1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   4484.75 4485.0  4485.25 4485.5  4485.75 4486.0  4486.25 4486.5  4486.75 4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
3   4484.75 4485.0  4485.25 4485.5  4485.75 4486.0  4486.25 4486.5  4486.75 4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
4   4484.75 4485.0  4485.25 4485.5  4485.75 4486.0  4486.25 4486.5  4486.75 4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5
5   4484.75 4485.0  4485.25 4485.5  4485.75 4486.0  4486.25 4486.5  4486.75 4487.0  4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25 4488.5  4488.75 4489.0  4489.25 4489.5

The first two rows of which are identifying values for the rest of rows (first row would be called Position, second row called Side).  I'd like to create column names, with these rows as identifiers, that will allow the df to be easily sliced along both rows and columns.
For instance, Id like to be able to filter the df according to column header values like this:
df.loc[:,[(df.Position.isin(0,1,2,3,4)) & (df.Side==0)]

Would return this subset of values:
    10      11      12      13      14
2   4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25
3   4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25
4   4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25
5   4487.25 4487.5  4487.75 4488.0  4488.25

I've tried the set_axis attribute, but this doesn't allow the column names to be referenced.  How would I achieve this?

Is this what you're looking for? Convert row to column header for Pandas DataFrame. If not, make a reproducible pandas example (with smaller data) and include the exact code you tried.

How are you loading this data? For example, if you're using read_csv, there are parser options you can use to load the column headers properly from the start.

@wjandrea They're not changing column headings. They just want a subset of columns, based on the values in rows 0 and 1.

how do you get your dataframe at the first place? If you use read_csv or similar, you. should consider passing the header=[0,1] param and then you can transform the dataframe, and/or stack/unstack the correct column level

Question doesn't seem very different from the one you have still open, with the same request as that of @wjandrea here, still pending. (and your isin is missing square brackets.)

@Barmar But they keep saying "column names"... How are you interpreting that?

@wjandrea I'm looking at the desired output, and its column names match those in the original data.

Why are all the data rows the same?

@wjandrea, in the linked to question, this would get me what I'm after (assuming I label columns thereafter) but only allows a single row (this throws the below error being it's 2-D):   df.columns = df.iloc[0:2] : ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

@QuangHoang, it's created from a different collection of input data, so not able to specify headers as part of this df's creation

Use pandas MultiIndex for MultiIndex columns:
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]], names=['Position', 'Side'])

df = df.drop([0, 1])

Then you can filter the df with these indexes:
df.iloc[:, (df.columns.get_level_values('Side') == 0) & (df.columns.get_level_values('Position').isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))]

Here is the full example:
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [4484.75, 4485.0, 4485.25, 4485.5, 4485.75, 4486.0, 4486.25, 4486.5, 4486.75, 4487.0, 4487.25, 4487.5, 4487.75, 4488.0, 4488.25, 4488.5, 4488.75, 4489.0, 4489.25, 4489.5],
    [4484.75, 4485.0, 4485.25, 4485.5, 4485.75, 4486.0, 4486.25, 4486.5, 4486.75, 4487.0, 4487.25, 4487.5, 4487.75, 4488.0, 4488.25, 4488.5, 4488.75, 4489.0, 4489.25, 4489.5],
    [4484.75, 4485.0, 4485.25, 4485.5, 4485.75, 4486.0, 4486.25, 4486.5, 4486.75, 4487.0, 4487.25, 4487.5, 4487.75, 4488.0, 4488.25, 4488.5, 4488.75, 4489.0, 4489.25, 4489.5],
    [4484.75, 4485.0, 4485.25, 4485.5, 4485.75, 4486.0, 4486.25, 4486.5, 4486.75, 4487.0, 4487.25, 4487.5, 4487.75, 4488.0, 4488.25, 4488.5, 4488.75, 4489.0, 4489.25, 4489.5]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set the first two rows as MultiIndex
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1]], names=['Position', 'Side'])
df = df.drop([0, 1])

print(df.iloc[:, (df.columns.get_level_values('Side') == 0) & (df.columns.get_level_values('Position').isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))])

Output:
Position      0.0     1.0      2.0     3.0      4.0
Side          0.0     0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0
2         4487.25  4487.5  4487.75  4488.0  4488.25
3         4487.25  4487.5  4487.75  4488.0  4488.25
4         4487.25  4487.5  4487.75  4488.0  4488.25
5         4487.25  4487.5  4487.75  4488.0  4488.25


Instead of get_level_values, we could use IndexSlice, which is a terser syntax: df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[[0,1,2,3,4], 0]] (shameless plugging of my own answer for more info)

Even for the original dataframe, df.loc[2:, df.iloc[0].isin([0,1,2,3,4]) & (df.iloc[1]==0)] is simple enough imo.

Totally agreed to both :)

@cottontail, appreciate it...IndexSlice is handy
